# how do i allow users to run .py commands for a discord bot

Tags: python, discord, bots

I am currently looking for an answer to a dilemma that I currently have. I created a discord bot for the RDO discord that I am on. The purpose of the discord bot is to track inactivity of members and will give a warning at a set amount of days to encourage the user to be active and a second warning for an impending kick and the bot after the 2nd warning will kick the user for inactivity. I have another option in the bot to put people on a special status that will prevent the bot of kicking them if they have an extended absence as well.

I wrote into the code for a command which is accessed with the "!" prefix. The user configurations should be as follows

`!set_activity_days`

The code for this bot command is listed below

```
@bot.command(name='set_activity_days')
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def set_activity_days(ctx, inactive_days_1: int, inactive_days_2: int):
  member = ctx.guild.get_member(ctx.guild.owner_id)
  member.activity_days_1 = inactive_days_1
  member.activity_days_2 = inactive_days_2
  await ctx.send(f"Activity days set successfully! Warning will be sent after {inactive_days_1} days of inactivity, and kick after {inactive_days_2} days of inactivity.")
```

when I tested this on my bot server it did not respond

Same went with the extended absence option that I created.

`!set_extended_absence`

The code for this section is below:

```
@bot.command(name='set_extended_absence')
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def set_extended_absence(ctx, member: discord.Member, extended_absence: bool):
  member.activity_extended_absence = extended_absence
  if extended_absence:
    await ctx.send(
      f"Extended absence status for {member.display_name} has been set to TRUE. The user will NOT receive kick warnings for inactivity."
    )
  else:
    await ctx.send(
      f"Extended absence status for {member.display_name} has been set to FALSE. The user will receive {bot.get_command('set_activity_days').name} for inactivity again."
    )
```

For the entire code see below:

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

TOKEN = 'Omitted the token due to security'

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

last_seen = {}

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f'Bot is ready. Logged in as {bot.user}')

@tasks.loop(hours=24)
async def check_inactivity():
  for guild in bot.guilds:
    inactive_days_1 = guild.get_member(guild.owner_id).activity_days_1
    inactive_days_2 = guild.get_member(guild.owner_id).activity_days_2

    for member in guild.members:
      if not member.bot:
        last_login = last_seen.get(member.id)
        if last_login:
          inactive_days = (datetime.now() - last_login).days
          if inactive_days == inactive_days_1:
            await member.send(
              f"It's been {inactive_days} days since you last logged in. Please consider joining in on the fun!"
            )
          elif inactive_days == inactive_days_2:
            if member.activity_extended_absence:
              continue
            await member.send(
              f"It's been {inactive_days} days since you last logged in. This is your {bot.get_command('set_activity_days').name}. You will be kicked if you remain inactive."
            )
          elif inactive_days > inactive_days_2:
            if member.activity_extended_absence:
              continue
            await member.send(
              "You have been inactive for too long. You will now be kicked from the server."
            )
            await member.kick(reason="Inactive for too long")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if not message.author.bot:
    last_seen[message.author.id] = datetime.now()
  await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.command(name='set_activity_days')
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def set_activity_days(ctx, inactive_days_1: int, inactive_days_2: int):
  member = ctx.guild.get_member(ctx.guild.owner_id)
  member.activity_days_1 = inactive_days_1
  member.activity_days_2 = inactive_days_2
  await ctx.send(f"Activity days set successfully! Warning will be sent after {inactive_days_1} days of inactivity, and kick after {inactive_days_2} days of inactivity.")

@bot.command(name='set_extended_absence')
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def set_extended_absence(ctx, member: discord.Member, extended_absence: bool):
  member.activity_extended_absence = extended_absence
  if extended_absence:
    await ctx.send(
      f"Extended absence status for {member.display_name} has been set to TRUE. The user will NOT receive kick warnings for inactivity."
    )
  else:
    await ctx.send(
      f"Extended absence status for {member.display_name} has been set to FALSE. The user will receive {bot.get_command('set_activity_days').name} for inactivity again."
    )

asyncio.run(check_inactivity())
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

To remedy this I tried removing `@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)` and it didn't work so it is back in.

I tried changing the prefix to the discord default which is "/" which did not work.

I know that the code is working because the bot does log in to the discord server but show no functionality to test.